# Any good research on observer effect and personality tests?

Tags: personality, test

I'm looking for some research on how / whether the 'observer effect' and 'observer bias' affects personality questionnaires. I recently completed the [16Personalities](https://www.16personalities.com/) test, a series of questions that drops you into a list of 16 personalities and gives a horoscope-like explanation of who you are.  I realised that I answered the questions based on my perception of my personality, and not necessarily what I would do. So if I think of myself as an introvert then I'm more likely to answer 'I am highly likely to feel awkward at a party.'

Then I read this article about how [narcissists can sometimes masquerade as sensitive introverts](https://getpocket.com/explore/item/23-signs-you-re-secretly-a-narcissist-masquerading-as-a-sensitive-introvert) - known as covert narcissists. What's to stop a covert narcissist from skewing their 16personalities answers to reflect a more pleasing view of themselves?

I think there is a bias issue with running a questionnaire in which you are both the observer and the subject, observing your own personality and giving responses that fit your perception of yourself. I was wondering whether anyone could point me to articles or research that look deeper into the observer effect in personality questionnaires.

Any help would be great!